# In JavaScript, how can one import classes and functions simply, like in python?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

My directory structure is currently as below:

```
˅ REACT-APP
|   > node_modules
|   > public
|   ˅ src
|   |   ˅ components
|   |   |   Home.js
|   |   ˅ custom-modules
|   |   |   number.js
|   |   |   give_me_number.js
|   |   App.js
|   |   index.js
|   .gitignore
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
```

The contents of `give_me_number.js`

```js
import someNumber from './give_me_number';
```

The contents of `number.js`

```js
var someNumber = 5;
export default someNumber;
```

trying to run `node give_me_number.js` will throw a warning `(node:7816)` and a `SyntaxError`:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What confuses me greatly is that I can easily access the default export of `Home.js` from `App.js`

The contents of `Home.js`

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Site Home</h1>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

The contents of `App.js`:

```js
/*...*/
import Home from './components/Home'

const App = () => {/*...*/}

export default App;
```

#### Full Error

```
(node:7816) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:...\react-app\src\custom-modules\give_me_number.js:1
import someNumber from './expressions';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you need to add the line:

```
"type: "module",
```

to your `package.json` file [in order to use ES6 modules].

Comment: Or name your files **.mjs" and give the full filename (with extension) "xyz.mjs" in the import statements

Comment: Why is it that this works just fine with the `App.js` / `Home.js` setup without this?

Comment: My guess would be that it's because they're first run through the JSX preprocessor.

Comment: Because in those cases you are not running node to run them. You are calling the React compiler which supports different syntax that node.js does not support. The React compiler will then output javascript files that does not contain the "import" syntax that older browsers that don't support the "import" syntax can execute